# PCIe DMA using mem=XXX allocation slow down, flow control credit issue

Tags: buffer, fpga, dma, pci-e, flow-control

I am trying to DMA from an FPGA into host PC (CentOS 6.9, 2.6.32 kernel) DDR4 memory using a descriptor bypass interface (no Scatter/Gather) and PCIe 3.0 x8.

What I did is set aside 240GB of RAM using mem=16384MB boot parameter (256GB of total RAM). I set the DMA address at 0x400000000 and increment it by Payload size (256 bytes) per descriptor.

What I am seeing is after ~50-60 KB, the transmission stall out/slow down significantly due to not receiving flow control credit. So at the start of a the transfer, I can send data at 6+ GB/s but after a little bit it slow down to like 100 MB/s.

What could be the problem? Is it due to the memory not being allocated correctly for DMA transfer?
Is it just something that I must take into account for my design, adding throttling in my FPGA logic? That doesn't seem right. I'm only trying to transmit 2GB/s of continuous data so I'd think there's enough bandwidth.

Comment: Your question is lacking relevant details. Which PC chipset? Which FPGA? How are you detecting the lack of flow control credit? Did you look at lspci -v to see how the BIOS and kernel are configuring your PCIE endpoint?

Comment: I am using Asus X99-E-10G WS and VCU108 (Virtex Ultrascale).